# Problem in updating field in codeigniter please help

Tags: codeigniter

It says , you must use the “set” method to update an entry. Pls help

My model is

```
$this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

My controller is

```
$data = $this->db->select('mytable', $_POST);
$this->contact_model->model_update_function($data);
```

Comment: What is the first line of your controller code doing there? Your example is a little confusing as to what it's trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$data` variable doesn't contain a valid array. This is because `$this->db->select();` doesn't actually run the query, you need `$this->db->get();` or `$this->db->get_where();` in order to do so. Even then, you also need to call `$query->result();` to retrieve the data from the result.

Your controller should be

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable', $_POST);
$data = $query->result();
$this->contact_model->model_update_function($data);
```

Comment: Thank you zackman, what do i need to do in order to update in multiple tables ? Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Just run the code in your model multiple times - once for each table.